# Excel - Matching if Cell Contains Substring Not Returning Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For some reason this will not return the matched row number for this specific substring. It works just fine with others.

EXAMPLE: Wanting to search/match and return which row contains the text "Tina Marie 5H,6H,7H 1 Initial_Visit"...searching through JR1:JR1000

Formula in JT3: `=MATCH("*"&"Tina Marie 5H,6H,7H 1 Initial_Visit"&"*",$JR$1:$JR$1000,0)`

If I even just search for "Tina", it returns the row beneath the first actual row...4 rather than 3

[Here is a demo of the erroring code for debug purposes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mXz0h2P-LDjclJI7ExZd2s74yfv2pL7R/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110394884905885480823&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[image]

[image]

Comment: They're pretty much just concatenations of multiple cells (I have a lot of values on each row and am grouping them). Even if I search for the number "5", it skips row 3 entirely and return 4. =MATCH("*"&"5"&"*",$JR$1:$JR$20,0)

Comment: I've added the file to Drive...the weird thing is that it seems to work just fine there? I'm running O365.

Comment: Yes the problem still exists in O365 Excel. However, the exact same code works fine in Google Sheets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243035/discussion-between-phil-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the length of the concatenated values, which would exceed 255 characters. Instead in `C2` try:

```
=LET(X,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&A2&" "&B2&" initial_visit*",D$2:AB$19)),ROW(D$2:AB$19)-1,"")),IF(X,X,""))
```

Comment: Bingo, thanks a mllion

Comment: @Phil, updated with a more direct and less proces-heavy way.